# Compute $I=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}(\sqrt[n]{a}+\frac{\sqrt[n]{b}-\sqrt[n]{c}}{d})^n$

Tags: limits

let $a,b,c,d>1$ and define
 $J=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}(1+\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{b})^n$.

So $$J=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}(1+\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{b})^n=
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} e^{n\ln (1+\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{b})}=a^{\frac{1}{b}}$$
Since 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} n\ln (1+\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{b})
=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\ln (1+\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{b})}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\frac{-\frac{1}{b}\frac{1}{n^2}\ln(a)\sqrt[n]{a} }{(1+\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1}{b})}}{-\frac{1}{n^2}}
=\frac{1}{b}\ln(a)=\ln (a^{\frac{1}{b}})$$.

Is there a better way. For example let

$I=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}(\sqrt[n]{a}+\frac{\sqrt[n]{b}-\sqrt[n]{c}}{d})^n$

How can you compute $I$?

```
 R Code 
 a<-3;b<-2;c<-4;d<-2
 n<-10000000
 part1<-a^(1/n)
 part2<-b^(1/n)
 part3<-c^(1/n)
 (part1+(part2-part3)/d)^n
  # output [1] 2.12132
```

Edit:Using  proposed   method by @Paramanand Singhmethod,$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1$.

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\ln (\sqrt[n]{a}+\frac{\sqrt[n]{b}-\sqrt[n]{c}}{d})}{\frac{1}{n}}=
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}
\frac{\ln \left(1+\sqrt[n]{a}-1+\frac{\sqrt[n]{b}-\sqrt[n]{c}}{d}\right)}{\sqrt[n]{a}-1+\frac{\sqrt[n]{b}-\sqrt[n]{c}}{d}}\frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1+\frac{\sqrt[n]{b}-\sqrt[n]{c}}{d}}{\frac{1}{n}}
$$

$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{a}-1+\frac{\sqrt[n]{b}-\sqrt[n]{c}}{d}}{\frac{1}{n}}$$

$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}  
\frac{-\frac{1}{n^2} \sqrt[n]{a} \ln a  -\frac{1}{d}\frac{1}{n^2} \sqrt[n]{b} \ln b
+\frac{1}{d}\frac{1}{n^2} \sqrt[n]{c} \ln c}{-\frac{1}{n^2}}
$$
$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}  
\sqrt[n]{a} \ln a  +\frac{1}{d}\sqrt[n]{b} \ln b
-\frac{1}{d}\sqrt[n]{c} \ln c
$$
$$= 
 \ln a  + \ln b^{\frac{1}{d}}
 -\ln c^{\frac{1}{d}}=\ln\left(a\left(b/c\right)^{\frac{1}{d}}\right)
$$ 
So $I=a\left(b/c\right)^{\frac{1}{d}}$

Comment: Take logs and use the standard limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\log(1+x)}{x}=1$.

Comment: You should get $a(b/c) ^{1/d}$ as the answer.